# Kill tomcat service running on any port, Windows

Tags: windows, tomcat, kill-process

Kill tomcat service running on any port, Windows
using command promt like 8080/ 8005

Answer (score 128, accepted):

1) Go to (Open) Command Prompt (Press **Window** + **R**  then type **cmd** Run this).

2) Run following commands

For all listening ports

## netstat -aon | find /i "listening"

Apply port filter

## netstat -aon |find /i "listening" |find "8080"

Finally with the PID we can run the following command to kill the process

*3) Copy PID from result set*

## taskkill /F /PID

Ex:  taskkill /F /PID 189

## Sometimes you need to run Command Prompt with Administrator privileges

Done !!! you can start your service now.

Comment: very useful - coming from ease of using linux shell commands *to* windows .... above command have been very useful

Comment: Or you could go a bit unnecessarily mad and put it all together on one line like so (adjust for port number!) 
`for /f "skip=1 tokens=5" %1 in ('netstat -aon ^| find "8080"') do taskkill /F /PID %1`

Comment: @ScalaEnthusiast I would gladly do that if I was comfortable in batch scripting. To me it seems more complex.

Comment: I would add a double colon in front of the port to prevent an accidental lookup in the PID column. So: `for /f "skip=1 tokens=5" %1 in ('netstat -aon ^| find ":8080"') do taskkill /F /PID %1`

Answer (score 5):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :3010
```

[image]

```
taskkill /F /PID
```

[image]

But it won't work for me

then I tried `taskkill -PID <processorid> -F`

Example:- `taskkill -PID 33192 -F` 
Here 33192  is the processorid and it works
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Based on all the info on the post, I created a little script to make the whole process easy.

```
@ECHO OFF
netstat -aon |find /i "listening"

SET killport=
SET /P killport=Enter port: 
IF "%killport%"=="" GOTO Kill

netstat -aon |find /i "listening" | find "%killport%"

:Kill
SET killpid=
SET /P killpid=Enter PID to kill: 
IF "%killpid%"=="" GOTO Error

ECHO Killing %killpid%!
taskkill /F /PID %killpid%

GOTO End
:Error
ECHO Nothing to kill! Bye bye!!
:End

pause
```