# could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: could not prepare statement

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i am working on a project using spring boot.:library management system.
In order to get the fines to be calculated, i have changed the system date. But, after that when i re-run the application, i am getting the following error
in console

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 8080 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be wrongly configured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: provide logs trace. Also change the port and try. server.port=8081

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have an instance of tomcat already running on port 8080. You need to kill the process for this, If using Java just kill the java process , if using linux kill the pid of the server.

Comment: how to kill the port

Comment: From command line in linux ps -A |grep java . And get pid of each elements. Kill with kill -9 PID command

Answer (score 0):

Seems like some other application is using that 8080 port. You can do two thing first kill that process which is using 8080 port another approach is to use another port for your application.
For this add following property in bootstrap.propeties file

```
server.port=9000
```

Comment: even i was using the another port, it was showing the same error.

Comment: how to kill the java process@Farrukh Ahmed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084188/kill-tomcat-service-running-on-any-port-windows
This will answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Two approachs;

- Open `task-manager` with `ctrl + alt  + delete`  , find with `java` process with `java` and `end task` them all and re-run project.
- From command line in linux `ps -A |grep java` . And get `pid` of each elements. Kill with `kill -9 PID` command.