# Spring boot 1.5 Tomcat still running

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I´m using spring boot version `1.5.13.RELEASE`, I cannot upgrade to another version so far.

Everything works fine, but when the maven job finish the tomcat process continue running, and always in the second execution I have a bind address exception.

Trying to stop as I´ve seen here [Terminating mvn spring-boot:run doesn't stop tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432651/terminating-mvn-spring-bootrun-doesnt-stop-tomcat)

I receive this log

```
18:19:16.390 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0
18:19:16.392 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10e8c7a2: startup date [Sun Sep 29 18:19:02 CEST 2019]; parent: org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@2b80497f
18:19:16.393 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor - Stopping beans in phase 0
18:19:16.393 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
18:19:16.393 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
18:19:16.393 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
18:19:16.395 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8093"]
18:19:16.452 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService - Stopping service [Tomcat]
18:19:16.455 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper - Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [com.app.JerseyConfig]
18:19:17.486 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper - Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [com.app.JerseyConfig]
18:19:18.511 [localhost-startStop-2] INFO  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper - Waiting for [1] instance(s) to be deallocated for Servlet [com.app.JerseyConfig]
18:19:18.638 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] INFO  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol - Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8093"]
18:19:18.644 [http-nio-8093-exec-4] WARN  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - The executor associated with thread pool [http-nio-8093] has not fully shutdown. Some application threads may still be running.
```

I´m running out of ideas. Suggestions without upgrade versions?

This is the Thread.dumpStack() before I finish

```
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1336)
    at com.ingbank.f2e.presentation.resource.SpringBootResource.closeApplication(SpringBootResource.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:143)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Regards

Comment: some thing went wrong plz terminate the tomcat port, for terminate follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42084188/kill-tomcat-service-running-on-any-port-windows

Comment: Judging by the presence of `JerseyConfig` in the logged output, the problem would appear to have something to do with Jersey. What does your configuration of Jersey look like? Also, can you try taking a thread dump and adding the output to your question? It should show which threads are left running that is preventing shutdown.

Comment: I put the dump generated, indeed glassfish of jersey is related with the deadlock